# Is there a way to use python to "continue" using an already existing open websocket that is in Chrome?

Tags: python, networking, websocket

Here is an example:
I use this website: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html and make a connection to the websocket.
Then I use python to send more messages using the same connection.

Is that possible?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to get into the encrypted connection from outside Chrome.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and find alternatives.